# list of functions with their description in Julia

Tags: julia

Hi I need to create a list of all functions from all installed packages with their description  from "help()" function. Now I have this code for create list of installed packages:

```
z=Array[collect(keys(Pkg.installed()))]
p=[z[1],"Base","Core"]
```

now in cycle I can read all functions from packages. But this error occur:

```
whos(p[1])
ERROR: no method whos(ASCIIString,)
```

how to use names in whos() function if they are stored as string?

the second problem I have is similar.

from all these functions I can read description by help() and store it also in array. How to do it?

Comment: I generated a website showing julia functions with examples:
http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/function-reference
In case you just want the end result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here.  First, as you noticed, the [`whos`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.whos) function does not have a method defined for ASCIIString arguments.  Looking at the output of [`methods(whos)`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.methods) reveals that it requires an argument of type Module.

```
julia> methods(whos)
# 4 methods for generic function "whos":
whos(m::Module,pattern::Regex) at show.jl:932
whos() at show.jl:939
whos(m::Module) at show.jl:940
whos(pat::Regex) at show.jl:941

julia> typeof(Base)
Module

julia> whos(Base)
⋮
```

You have a string with the name of a module, like "Base". This is where `eval` comes in.  You must evaluate the module's name (as a symbol) to get the actual Module itself. So, for example, `eval(symbol("Base"))` will first convert "Base" to the symbol `:Base` (which is still just a name, but it's now a name that Julia will recognize as an identifier), and then evaluate it to get the real Module Base.

But you can't get a Module (or look inside it) without first importing it. We have to `import` each module before it's name is defined. Doing so programmatically with each of the names from `Pkg.installed()` will take a bit of [metaprogramming](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/).  This, too, is tricky, because the import statement is restricted in where it can appear (must be in a top-level scope) and how it is parsed (must be on its own line, and interpolation within a `quote` block is not supported).  So unfortunately this solution can't be put into a function, for example (there are ways around this: you could manually `include` each package's top-level file manually, but that requires a bit more pathing logic).

Instead of printing everything out, let's aggregate the results into a nested dictionary, where the top-level dictionary will have the packages as its keys, and the sub-dictionaries will have the exported names of each module as their keys.

```
julia> d = Dict{Symbol,Any}()
       for pkg in map(symbol, keys(Pkg.installed()))
         eval(Expr(:import, pkg)) # Manually put the import statement into an Expr
         ks = names(eval(pkg))
         vs = zeros(UTF8String,length(ks))
         for (i,k) in enumerate(ks)
           # packages can export undefined names, which would throw an error
           try
             vs[i] = summary(eval(:($pkg.$k)))
           end
         end
         d[pkg] = Dict(ks,vs)
       end

julia> d[:Gadfly][:plot]
"Function"
```

Since we're iterating through lots of modules, I'm using `import` instead of `using` to prevent clashes between the exported names.  That means that when referencing each exported name, I need to fully qualify it with the PackageName.  That's what `eval(:($pkg.$k))` is doing, via [interpolation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#eval-and-interpolation). If a package exports a name but leaves it undefined, accessing it would throw an error.  So it must be wrapped in a try block.

You can change the `summary` command to be whatever you want, but unfortunately packages cannot hook into the `help` system (yet), so asking for the help text via `sprint(help, …)` won't give you anything much more informative than summary.